# How to load a template using the new laravel-excel 3.1?

Tags: laravel, spreadsheet, laravel-excel

I im trying to load a excel template file using laravel-excel, but cant find any answer on the docs

Comment: What do you mean by load a template? Using laravel-excel you can read or write excel files from different source, can you specify more precisely what is your need?

Comment: i want to import an excel file then populate it with my model.. the scenario is i have a template excel file with formulas and formatting on it, i just want to load it then put data in it so that i dont have to manually style to cells and add formulas in them through code

Answer (score 2):

Your Controllers

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use App\Http\Controllers\ImportController;

class ExportController extends Controller
{

   /**
    * Display a listing of the resource.
    * @author Matin Malek
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */
   public function generateFile() {
      return Excel::download(new \App\Export, 'sample.xlsx');
   }


}
```

Your Model File

```
 <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\AfterSheet;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithCustomStartCell;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMapping;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithStartRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\BeforeExport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\BeforeSheet;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\BeforeWriting;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel;

class Export implements WithEvents
{
    /**
    * Export data 
    * @author Matin Malek
    * @return Array
    */
    public function registerEvents(): array
    {
      return [
         BeforeExport::class => function(BeforeExport $event){
            $event->writer->reopen(new \Maatwebsite\Excel\Files\LocalTemporaryFile(storage_path('filename.xlsx')),Excel::XLSX);

            $event->writer->getSheetByIndex(0);
            $event->getWriter()->getSheetByIndex(0)->setCellValue('A1','Your Value');
            return $event->getWriter()->getSheetByIndex(0);
         }
      ];
    }
}
```

I am not sure this is right way or not. But you can do it by this code in your laravel model file.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Import Dependencies
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;

//Inside your function
$reader = IOFactory::createReader('Xlsx');
$spreadsheet = $reader->load('path_to\excel_file.xlsx');

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="SF2.xlsx"');
$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save('php://output');
//End of your function
```

Hope it helps. This is how I do it on my project

Answer (score 0):

You can find solution here [here](https://github.com/SpartnerNL/Laravel-Excel/issues/2068).

Full working solution:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\BeforeWriting;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Files\LocalTemporaryFile;
use DB;

class SomeExportClass implements FromCollection, WithEvents
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->calledByEvent = false;
    }

    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    public function collection()
    {
        if ($this->calledByEvent) { //check flag
            return DB::table('some_table')->get();
        }
    
        return collect([]);

    }

    public function registerEvents(): array
    {

        return [
            BeforeWriting::class => function(BeforeWriting $event) {
                $templateFile = new LocalTemporaryFile(storage_path('app/excel_templates/SomeTemplate.xls'));
                $event->writer->reopen($templateFile, Excel::XLS);
                $event->writer->getSheetByIndex(0);
                $this->calledByEvent = true; // set the flag
                $event->writer->getSheetByIndex(0)->export($event->getConcernable()); // call the export on the first sheet
    
                return $event->getWriter()->getSheetByIndex(0);
            },
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;

class UsersImport implements ToCollection {

    public function collection(Collection $rows) {

        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            User::create([
                'name'     => $row[0],
                'email'    => $row[1],
                'password' => Hash::make($row[2]),
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Another example...

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;

class UsersImport implements ToModel {

    /**
     * @param array $row
     *
     * @return User|null
     */
    public function model(array $row) {
        return new User([
            'name'     => $row[0],
            'email'    => $row[1],
            'password' => Hash::make($row[2]),
        ]);
    }
}
```

You will find more examples here ... https://github.com/Maatwebsite/laravel-excel-docs/tree/master/3.1/imports

Comment: this is not what i meant... what i mean is to load an existing template then papulate it with details then download. simple as that

Comment: The Question is for loading a template not asking for different ways of exporting data,